# Regular expression Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Good Morning in my timezone

I want to replace a character that is in the beginning of each line
So i had used the following regular expression to find the text

> ^\d

And it works fine in finding all the characters
The problem is in the replace with
I want to replace with single quote followed by the same character found above
How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50737583/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*:      `^\d`
*Replace With*: `'$0`

where `$0` is the backreference to the match value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try this option:

**Find:**

```
^(?=\d)
```

**Replace:**

```
'           <-- just a single quote
```

The find pattern uses a positive lookahead which asserts that the first character is a digit, but nothing is ever matched.  Then, the replacement is a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Another one would be:

Find:

```
^(\d)
```

Replace:

```
'\1
```

In this example `\1` would be 1st captured group.